# Check if site is alive through Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-applications, dns, ping

I`ve build a simple project in nodejs to understand how things works. Everything looks fine on my local server, but when I push this to some cloud(Heroku) I get some strange errors.

The app baseline consist in checking if an address(hostname or ip) is "alive", so I've decided to try some of ping packages on npm(ping and ping-lite). Both of them works properly on my localserver, but when pushed to heroku i got this:

`/app/node_modules/ping-lite/ping-lite.js:39
throw new Error('Could not detect '+this._bin+' on your system');`

I do not understand a lot of network/tcp-ip stuff, but both of this packages are wrappers for "sys ping" does this mean that I can't use these  because heroku does not allow performing a sys ping?

If that is true what I could do to check if an address is alive?

> Note: I`m currently doing a http get request to check this, but this do not work with address like (8.8.8.8, dns or public dns) .

Comment: Why won't using a `GET` or `HEAD` request work? You can get an ip address directly, there should be no problem. What is `dns` or `public dns`?

Comment: And yes, Heroku wouldn't have the underlying `bin` directory, nor probably a ping binary to call.

Comment: I know almost nothing about networks and tcp/ip stuffs, but a http request do not work with 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Comment: What error are you getting when trying to make the http request to those addresses?

Comment: No error. But no "response" either. My main answer was about the underlying bin directory, but thanks for your answer.